# "TLS Handshake timeout" when installing aws-sdk-go package with go get

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, ssl, aws-sdk-go

I am getting `net/http: TLS handshake timeout` when trying to install `aws-sdk-go` with `go get`.

```
go get -v github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.30.10
go get: github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.30.10: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/proxy-golang-org-prod/153044bb636484b4-github.com:aws:aws-sdk-go-v1.30.10.zip?Expires=1587550038&GoogleAccessId=gcs-urlsigner-prod%40golang-modproxy.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Signature=Py%2Fu6vp6bq%2F%2Bz57LXE4oUVTvCjAL08bnxnlWuHUh2FME7v89fzIz1%2FNOJ5kKsXCJV39OMJLsjF5j3457p1mZJsBZSgTjMnFbPbuVRHu%2FhKPFPmvVsLYvchvB7Va%2F%2BGcyYHhOsP0XMdSo3N8GjqltihMWfKML49RNOmqCrQT%2F0Qc1b%2BBhbz9iH88QNd9mSwYYQpr0kuAVOb3OGfyQGY11vrTHLWp5ammOH%2B6Xa7g5cpCMO91Ane8aOEYywc0oSsgvv4y32qp0G%2FGm18pDHzLq1o0OA7HEKUU59ACFpOsTyEhF0uECBoNfFpiBuOub%2BY%2FMhGzsojk1dW0vzmR0SOGxqg%3D%3D: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I can install any other go packages without any trouble. And my colleagues (in different network) can install `aws-sdk-go` without any problem. But, I am continuously facing this problem. I have tried with two different laptops. I have also tried switching to 3G network instead of broadband but, no luck there too.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Could have been a service issue with proxy.golang.org - try it with the module proxy disabled, see https://proxy.golang.org/ for info.

Comment: @Adrian thanks a lot, it seems problem was with proxy `GOPROXY=direct go get -v github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go` solved the the problem.

Comment: @Adrian, you can add your comment as an answer, it may help others find the answer quickly. I will mark it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: If it was a temporary issue with proxy.golang.org then it's not a "solution" really and the question should be closed as temporary/non-reproducible.